# JQuery UI catcomplete not returning selected result

Tags: html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using JQuery UI remote autocomplete with Categories.

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            cat = currentCategory;
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
    }
});

$(function() {
        $( "#birds" ).catcomplete({
            delay:0,
            source: "/search.html?term="+ $("#birds").val(),
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ){
            alert(ui.item.value);
            }
        });     
});
```

The following is the result I get from the source:

[{"value":"Just a Product","id":"1","category":"Category Name"}]

The problem is that I can't get the alert(ui.item.value) to work and display the selected item.

Any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: Look in your Error-Console ..

Comment: TypeError: ui.item is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

alert(ui.item.value);

Comment: So change alert(ui.item.value) to console.log(event, ui); You can now look (in the console) what properties the ui/event has and wich property you need to access.

Comment: What if my property isn't there?

Comment: Maybe.. I Noticed that without showing the categories... it would work perfectly. But I need the categories ..

Comment: So you could look in the debug output in which property stands what you are looking for and then access this property.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you deal with the source.
see this.. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source
you can use

- array
- string
- callback function

if you want to receive data from a page in json format, use jquery's $.ajax()
see this for ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

you can do something like

```
$.ajax({url: 'search.php?term='+$("#birds").val(),
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
},
async: false,
success: function(data){
bArray=new Array;
bJson=data;
bArray.push(bJson[0].value);
bArray.push(bJson[0].id);
bArray.push(bJson[0].category);// for multiple records put these 3 lines in loop and replace 0 with a counter
}
});

$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
source: bArray,
select:function(event,ui)
{alert(ui.item.value);}     
});
```

dont forget to declare bArray, bJson

BUT i would still say you are doing it wrong. Instead of using value,id,category together you use use only one of them as autocomplete. can you tell what are you exactly showing in autocomplete